# F# bind option and a task

Tags: .net-core, f#, c#-to-f#

I want to to replicate the following C# code:

```cs
var things = url is null ? null : await GetThings(url);
```

What I got is:

```ml
 task {
            match urlOption with
            | None -> return None
            | Some url ->
                let! things = this.GetThings(url)
                return things |> Some
        }
```

I excpected to be able to do something like:

```ml
let! things = url >>= this.GetThings
```

Am I missing some operator declarations? Probably, but do I need to write them on my own or is there a library?

I found [Fsharp.Plus](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/) but I have no idea whether this does not have what I want, or I just do it wrong.

Comment: I think this is one of the cases where F# is just longer than C#. If you are writing something like this repeatedly, you could come up with a helper function to make your code shorter. If this is in just one or two places, I would accept it as it is. FSharp.Plus may have a way of doing that, but it will lead to more complex code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it with F#+ but you need to wrap it in an `OptionT`:

```
#r "nuget: FSharpPlus"

open System
open System.Threading.Tasks
open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data

let x = Task.FromResult (Some 42)
let f x = Task.FromResult (Some x)

let y =
    OptionT x
    >>= (OptionT << f) 
    |> OptionT.run
```

Then you can use the `>>=` operator as demonstrated above or the generic `monad`` computation expression.